# svn and git: View all changes of one user

Tags: git, svn, web-applications, gitweb

We have several svn and git repositories.

I want to have a view (web) where I can see:

All changes of user "foo" on day yyyy-mm-dd.

The result should be sorted by time and it should not matter if a change was made in svn or git.

If you know a tool or have a hint how to get this, please let me know it.

Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129152/are-there-open-source-alternatives-to-bitbucket-github-kiln-and-similar-dvcs

Answer (score 0):

SCM-Manager should let you manage `git` and `svn` repositories: http://www.scm-manager.org/

Answer (score 0):

project management and bug-tracking tool like [redmine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmine) or [trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) should be able to spit out this information if you have the repositories linked there.

also see: [fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/overview)